# How to add event listener to class in Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, android, animation, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to set an eventListener to a class. I use the view to make a custom button and I set the animation by its id. But I need to set the animation by class and not by id. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
var animation = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
animation.backgroundColor = '#017695'; 
animation.duration = 400; 
function setWhite(e) { $.pulValutaAmici.backgroundColor= "#fff"; }; 

animation.addEventListener('complete', setWhite); 
$.pulValutaAmici.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
    $.pulValutaAmici.animate(animation)});
var valuta = Alloy.createController("valuta").getView();
valuta.open();
```

Comment: what you have tried already ??

Comment: Actually I use an eventListener for each element I want animate. But this is not a good way, the code is useless large.

here my code:

var animation = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
     animation.backgroundColor = '#017695';
     animation.duration = 400;
     ;
     
function setWhite(e) { $.pulValutaAmici.backgroundColor= "#fff"; };  
   
animation.addEventListener('complete', setWhite);

$.pulValutaAmici.addEventListener('click', function(e){ $.pulValutaAmici.animate(animation); var valuta = Alloy.createController("valuta").getView(); valuta.open(); });

Comment: AFAIK you cannot directly use class for event listener. More [info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542594/dynamic-style-change-in-titanium-alloy).